# Mongodb - promoting data from staging to prod environment

Tags: mongodb, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have prod and staging environments for Mongodb. I have good amount of  data entered it staging environment for every release which will go through testing process. Once the testing is done, I would like to move those changes to production environment just before release. If the data is entered manually into production environment, there are chances for mistakes. So I would like to avoid manually entering data to production and promote changes (only delta) made in staging environment.

Is there any way to achieve this with Mongodb? I cannot take whole dump of a collection and import into production as majority of the data must have been there in production.

Comment: Are you sure it's wise to promote test data to production?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Good question. The organization that I am working doesn't want to write anything to production directly. We have a pre-prod environment (uses separate db instance) where changes are made (changes which are supposed to go to production). After testing in pre-prod, we would like to pull changes into prod. Data is entered through UI and no.of changes are huge. We cannot track all of them as queries. So we would like to pull them.